# What is the module: 'test' used for?

Tags: python

I found some weird code:

```py
all_modules_ = [
    'BaseHTTPServer', 'imaplib'
]

for module in all_modules_:
    print(module)
    m = __import__('test')
```

and I got:

```
» python test.py
BaseHTTPServer
BaseHTTPServer
imaplib
imaplib
```

Why is this?

And the result in ipython seems normal:

```
In [2]: all_modules_ = [
   ...:     'BaseHTTPServer', 'imaplib'
   ...: ]
   ...:
   ...: for module in all_modules_:
   ...:     print(module)
   ...:     m = __import__('test')
   ...:
   ...:
BaseHTTPServer
imaplib
```

Comment: Please clarify your confusion. test is your own module.

Comment: In that code, it's not being used. It is just discarded. [test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html) is the python self-testing module.

Comment: @FHTMitchell The file is called test.py and executed in its containing directory. That puts it first on the module search path. Only in ipython is it not on the search path, because there is no test.py script being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `test.py`, [it runs the module as `__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html). Since the module executes `__import__(„test“)`, it runs the module again as `test`. Thus, you see each output again.

Since Python does not re-import modules under the same name, you do not get the output more than twice.

When running in ipython, your module does not exist. The standard library module test is run once instead. Since it produces no output, you only see your own output, once.